# 13.10 mouse and keyboard slow to start after reboot

Tags: keyboard, 13.10, mouse, reboot

After a reboot which I do because of other issues, the mouse and keyboard drivers are slow to load up to two minutes after wireless is established.

This started after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 in fact a couple times my mouse disappeared and I had to research without a mouse.

I was able to get the mouse working when it disappeared with this command :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

What can I do to load the mouse and keyboard like before instantly upon reboot ?